# Pairing files in linux

Tags: python, linux, perl, bash, unix

I have in a directory a big number of files and their translation in other languages. There are files in 10 different languages and files in 2 or 3. A typical name of a file is `xx_xxxx_EN.html` and its translation xx_xxxx_IT.html . I want to extract a 2 column txt file with the names of the files. For example for the English - Italian language pair:
`xx_xxxx_EN.html xx_xxxx_IT.html`

Comment: ...Or what have you searched ?

Comment: `ls >> output.txt` should so the trick?

Comment: @Kush if the trick is to append the output of `ls` to `output.txt` then I guess you're correct!?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash 

ls -1 *EN.html | while IFS= read -r file
do 
    ls -1 ${file%_*}* | while IFS= read -r match
    do
    if [ "$file" != "$match" ]; then 
        echo "$file" "$match"
    fi 
    done 
done
```

---

```
$ ls *html 
01_DE.html 01_EN.html 01_ESP.html 01_IT.html 02_EN.html 02_IT.html 02_PL.html

$ ./pair.sh

01_EN.html 01_DE.html
01_EN.html 01_ESP.html
01_EN.html 01_IT.html
02_EN.html 02_IT.html
02_EN.html 02_PL.html
```

Comment: @lion my understanding was that was the point, the OP has a bunch of non-english files that they want to be pair matched with.